ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS error when initializing SecretManagerServiceClient in Node.js
I'm trying to use Google Cloud's Secret Manager in my Node.js application, but I'm encountering an ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS error when initializing the SecretManagerServiceClient. Here's my code:
const {SecretManagerServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager').v1;

export async function accessSecretVersion() {
    let client;
    try {
        client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

When I run this code, I get the following error:

[ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]: "length" is outside of buffer bounds
    at proto.utf8Write (node:internal/buffer:1066:13)
    at Op.writeStringBuffer [as fn] (/app/node_modules/protobufjs/src/writer_buffer.js:61:13)
    at BufferWriter.finish (/app/node_modules/protobufjs/src/writer.js:453:14)
    at /app/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:152:109
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createPackageDefinition (/app/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:152:39)
    at Object.fromJSON (/app/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:205:12)
    at GrpcClient.loadProtoJSON (/app/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:228:51)
    at new SecretManagerServiceClient (/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/build/src/v1/secret_manager_service_client.js:142:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/secrets.js:38:22) {
  code: 'ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS'
}


I'm not sure why this is happening, as I'm simply trying to initialize the client. Here are some additional details:
Node.js version: 11.15.21
@google-cloud/secret-manager version: 4.2.2
I've already tried:
Updating all dependencies
Deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling
Any ideas on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

Curiously someone else (using a different Google Cloud Node.js SDK) is experiencing a similar issue (see 78911536. This may be a Google issue.

I am unable to repro your issue using the latest (5.6.0) version of @google-cloud/secret-manager

Perhaps: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/54518

i faced the same issue with grp i did 2 things:
changed node.js version. what is working right now for me is 18.17.0.
also if you are using docker do not use 'alpine' images.
second thing i added "grpc.max_receive_message_length": length number,
"grpc.max_send_message_length": length number to the server and client options.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

As @DazWilkin referenced, this looks exactly like a pretty broadly well-known issue with Node 22.7.0, and indeed I am getting the exact same error output with SecretManagerServiceClient on Node 22.7.0.
I can't find a reference to your node version (11.15.21), particularly the patch level 21, so I'm wondering if you're using a different version and seeing the same error as the rest of us.
If so, good news is 22.5.1 works great as other have stated (and for me as well), and a fix for the issue in 22.7 is imminent, in 22.8:
Per https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/54524#issuecomment-2313117894

It should go out tomorrow. Follow #54560

